# How can I disable chunk(code splitting) with webpack4?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created react project with : yarn create react-app. I'm using webpack 4.29.6, react 16.8.6.

I want to disable code splitting because I want just one 'main.js' file in build/static/js folder. (I already removed hash from their names.)

I tried:

```
new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
    maxChunks: 1
  }),
```

and

```
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
        cacheGroups: {
          default:false
        }
      }
```

but these solutions give me these files:

```
build
  /static
   /js
   -2.chunk.js
   -2.chunk.js.map
   -main.chunk.js
   -main.chunk.js.map
   -runtime~main.js
   -runtime~main.js.map
```

I think runtime~main.js file and .map file are just okay, but I want the exact 'main.js' file without chunk, without 2.chunk.js. How can I disable default code splitting of webpack 4?

Comment: Hi, did get any solution to this problem?

Comment: @Kishore Barik Yes but I’m not sure that this is desirable solution. I just deleted all options related to chunk.

Comment: Is it just as simple as having 1 input and 1 output file? https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you created your project with [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and haven't yet ejected, it appears you have two options currently available:

**Option 1 - Create a custom build script**

First, install the package [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) as a dependency:

```
npm install rewire
```

Create a `scripts` folder, inside create a new file and give it a name e.g., `build-non-split.js`, then add:

```
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
let config = defaults.__get__('config');

config.optimization.splitChunks = {
    cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
    },
};

config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
```

Modify `package.json`, inside `"scripts"` and replace `build` with:

```
"build": "node ./scripts/build-non-split.js",
```

Finally, run `npm run build` or `yarn build`

**Option 2 - Install the package [`react-app-rewire-disable-chunks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewire-disable-chunks)**

**Note**: If you go with this option, don't forget to replace the `build` script with `react-app-rewired`. Like this:

```
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
```

Source: [Disabling code splitting in CRA2 #5306](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-433425838)

Comment: Neither of these options appear to be working for me for webpack version 5.76.0, react version 18.1.0. I will keep digging.

Comment: Ah - I was able to find a workaround that stopped the chunk from being split off. I was using `import()` to reference a file in a custom hook, which caused webpack to split the file into its own chunk as it considered it a module rather than just some JSON I needed. When I replaced `import()` with `require()` instead, no need for a separate chunk.

Answer (score 20):

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1
    })
]
```

Try if this works. Install this manually `LimitChunkCountPlugin`

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/