# How to create single build file for react application created using graphiql

Tags: reactjs, graphiql

I have created a `graphql` application using `react` and its working fine on dev environment
But on production its is giving chunk error as my app deployed on different host.

I m using these packages

```
    "@graphiql/plugin-explorer": "1.0.3",
    "codemirror-graphql": "2.0.10",
    "graphiql": "3.1.1",
    "graphql": "16.8.1",
    "graphql-language-service-cli": "3.3.33",
```

[image]

[image]

Is there any way we can create single bundle of application ?

Comment: Where have you deployed the app? Can you share more details about it

Comment: If you are sure that you want to create a single bundle rather than using code splitting, you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993890/how-can-i-disable-chunkcode-splitting-with-webpack4